# Programmatically click buttons on Android Emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, testing, android-emulator

I have a solution for visual studio, which consists of speech-synthesizer code and packaging for android. And I'd like to perform some test, but not manually. I'd like to write program that would click buttons in Android Emulator.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a tool called monkeyrunner, Please refer to [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html)

all you need to do is write some scripts.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) can be used to create scripts and tests that interact with the UI.

[Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) also helps you generate those scripts automatically interacting with the device representation.